# How to pass current scope to a Controller function in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to do something like below:

```
  <ul>
       <li ng-click="GetBookDetails({{book.id}})" ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.Title}}</li>                        
  </ul>
```

Below is the controller:

```
 angular.module('app')
.controller("Books", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.books = data.items;
    })

    $scope.GetBookDetails = function (bookId) {
        $http.get(url + '/' + bookId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.bookDetails = data;
        })
    }
}]);
```

But ng-click="GetBookDetails({{book.id}})" this is giving invalid key error.
Could you please help me out?

Comment: `ng-click="GetBookDetails(book.id)"` you don't need to interpolate `{{book.id}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ng-click="GetBookDetails(book.id)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-click="GetBookDetails(book.id)"
```

You must not use interpolation in an angular expression.

You should also respect the naming conventions and rename your function to `getBookDetails()`, and the `Title` attribute to `title`. You'll lose much time and introduce bugs if you have to wonder, every time you use a function or an attribute, if it starts with a lowercase letter or not.

Finally, success() and error() callbacks on $http promises are deprecated. You should use then(), as for any other promise:

```
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    $scope.books = response.data.items;
})
```